# Why is my Rfacebook loop script not working when there is a post with zero comments?

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, rfacebook

**I've edited my question to be more relevant**

It's only been less than a month since I started to learn R and I'm trying to use it to get rid of the tedious work related to Facebook (extracting comments) that we use for our reports.

Using ***Rfacebook*** package, i made this script where it extracts **(1) the posts of the page for a given period, and (2) Comments on those posts**. It worked well for the page I'm doing the report for, but when I tried it on other pages with posts that had zero comments, it reported an error.

**Here's the script:**
Loading libraries

```
library(Rfacebook)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
```

Setting time period. Change time as you please.

```
current_date <-Sys.Date()
past30days<-current_date-30
```

Assigning a page. Edit this to the page you are monitoring*

```
brand<-'bpi'
```

Authenticating Facebook. Use your own

```
app_id <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
app_secret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
token <- fbOAuth(app_id,app_secret,extended_permissions = FALSE,legacy_permissions = FALSE)
```

Extract all posts from a page

```
listofposts <- getPage(brand, token, n = 5000, since = past30days, until = current_date, feed = FALSE, reactions = FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
write.csv(listofposts,file = paste0('AsOf',current_date,brand,'Posts','.csv'))
```

Convert to a data frame

```
df<-as_tibble(listofposts)
```

Convert to a vector

```
postidvector<-df[["id"]]
```

Get the number of posts in the period

```
n<-length(postidvector)
```

Produce all comments via loop

```
reactions<-vector("list",n)
for(i in 1:n){
  reactions[[i]]<-assign(paste(brand,'Comments', i, sep = ""), (getPost((postidvector[i]),token,comments=T,likes=F,n.likes=5000,n.comments=10000))) 
}
```

Extract all comments per post to CSV

```
for(j in 1:n){
  write.csv(reactions[[j]],file = paste0('AsOf',current_date,brand,'Comments' ,j, '.csv'))
}
```

**Here's the error when exporting the comments to CSV when I tried it on the 
 pages with posts that had ZERO comments:**

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

I tried it on a heavy traffic page, and it worked fine too. One post had 10,000 comments and it extracted just fine. :(

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 2):

Pages can be restricted by age or location. You can´t use an App Access Token for those, because it does not include a user session so Facebook does not know if you are allowed to see the Page content. You will have to use a User Token or Page Token for those.

Comment: App Access Token is independent of session and considered to be a permanent token. So it might work for you.

Comment: @Aditi if the page is restricted, it can´t work with an app token ;)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention about "public page" :)

Comment: all pages are public, but some are restricted by age or location. i am still not sure what you want to say, to be honest.

Comment: All pages are public :)

I think I already saw where it goes wrong. Sometimes when a post has no comments, the loop breaks.